# How do I ignore an exception thrown by a private void method using easymock?

Tags: java, exception, mocking, void, easymock

I have a void method that does something.  I do not care what it does in my unit test class.  However, it is throwing exception when I call it from my unit-test class and it is causing my test cases to fail.

How can I, using EasyMock, mock this object so that when this void method gets called, I ignore what it does in my unit test?

For example, let's say the object is called `myObject` and it has a void method called `doSomething()`.
EasyMock doesn't let me use 'expect' because it is a void method that returns nothing.  But when I call this method in my test case, it throws an exception (which I want to completely ignore).

I know this can be achieved by maybe using mockito or other libs, but I'd like to use EasyMock.

*UPDATE*

the method in question is a private void method which gets called by other processes. i cannot call it directly but i still want to ignore the exception that's thrown by that private void method.

i've tried using nice mock as suggested as below.

```
MyObject obj = EasyMock.createNiceMock(MyObject.class);
EasyMock.replay(obj);
```

and then i set this obj in another object that contains it as private variable.

```
MyObject2 obj2 = new MyObject2();
obj2.setMyObject(obj);
```

and i call some method that calls the private void method internally.

```
obj2.methodThatCallsPrivateVoidMethod();
```

and this did not work.

Comment: If the method you want to mock is private, then you won't be able to mock it with EasyMock, you'll need to use [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/). Having said that, from the look of the rest of your question, there is an accessible method on MyObject (public, protected, default) that you can mock out, correct?

Comment: yes but that public method is something i want to unit test. it's just so that i can ignore private void method's outcome (especially the exception which is inherently there)

Comment: In that case, you'll have to produce a partial mock of MyObject using PowerMock to mock the private method. It's possible, but kind of awkward. [Here's the documentation for it](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockPrivate)

Answer (score 0):

Without using EasyMock, a common approach to this is to override the problematic method in a testable version of your class.

Assuming this is your class

```
class MyClass {
   ...
   public void doSomething() {
    ...
    }
}
```

Do this in your test:

```
public class MyTestClass {

   @Test
   public void testThis {
      MyClass myObject = new TestableMyClass();
      ...
      // Now you can invoke methods on myObject and the 
      // doSomething() method will be harmless.
   }

   class TestableMyClass extends MyClass {
      @Override
      public void doSomething {
         // Do nothing.  Thus no exception.
      }
   }
}
```

Note that EasyMock may provide a similar way to do this, but I am not familiar with EasyMock.  I know that this is not a problem with Mockito.